# setState on button click and post axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this on the front end (react) right now.

```
  import '../styles/TourPage.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'


class TourPage extends Component {
  
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {
            myData: []
          }
    }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('/getResults')
      .then( res => {
        console.log("Res is: ", res.data)
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
       
      })
      console.log("res.data", this.state.myData)
  }

  

  render() {
    console.log("res.data", this.state.myData)
    return (

        <table id="customers">
              <tr>
                <th>siteLocation</th>
                <th>Services</th>
                <th>cnum</th>
              </tr>
              {this.state.myData.length > 0? this.state.myData.map((data, index) => (
          <tr>
         
                  {/* <tr key={index}> */}
                    <td>{data.location}</td>
                    <td>{data.Services}</td>
                    <td>{data.cnum}</td>
                    <button onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}> Delete </button>
                {/* {this.state.data} */}

                  {/* </tr> */}
              
          </tr>
            ))
            : "No Data Found"}
        </table>

    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

What I want to do, is on a button click, set `data._id` in the state, and then call Axios to post it to the Node.JS backend server, so I can update the database. Basically to delete the document. as you can see below, I tried with `<a href>` but that seems to be an HTML-specific thing. I also tried with the button, but I cannot figure it out. How can I do this?

Comment: Do a basic tutorial on react + axios and you'll figure it out

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: @VJR08 just posted the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored most of your code. You can pass id using an anonymous arrow function.

Do modify this to suit your needs.

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/TourPage.css";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/getResults")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  deleteById = (id) => {
    // You'll get the id here
    // Delete by id code goes here
  };

  render() {
    // You can handle the loader part here with isLoading flag. In this case No data found will be shown initially and then the actual data
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>siteLocation</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
          ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{location}</td>
                <td>{Services}</td>
                <td>{cnum}</td>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.deleteById(_id)}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </tr>
            ))
          : "No Data Found"}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
 render() {
    deleteDoc = (id) => {
        await fetch('service_url', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: id} )
        .then(async response => {
          await response.json().then(data => {
           console.log(data);
          });
        }) 
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return (

        <table id="customers">
            <tr>
                <th>siteLocation</th>
                <th>Services</th>
                <th>cnum</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.myData.length > 0 ? this.state.myData.map((data, index) => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{data.location}</td>
                    <td>{data.Services}</td>
                    <td>{data.cnum}</td>
                    <button onClick={this.deleteDoc(data._id)} disabled={this.state.isLoading}> Delete </button>

                </tr>
            ))
                : "No Data Found"}
        </table>

    );
}
```

Comment: it says `deleteDoc` is undefined

Comment: Add this to bottom;
}
export default TourPage;

Comment: yes, I made that mistake, sorry :(. fixed it tho. now It is saying deleteDoc is undefined